# Weird clouds appearing when converting mesh into SDF

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, geometry, topology, remesh

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubfb2K6mL0&ab_channel=BadNormals) on how to morph one object into another. It converts an object into an SDF, similar to a Metaball, so they can merge together. It works for most objects, but the ones I am trying to use have these weird cloud shapes appearing far outside of the geometry. I've tried it on several other complex models (Downloaded from Adobe Mixamo) but none of them replicated the issue. There are no other vertices or anything off to the side there that would cause that to happen. What's going on?

[image: bruh]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's probably a limitation to to the setup presented in the tutorial. There are too many intricate parts in your model which cause the morph process (with the "clouds") to be more out of place. [As you can see here](https://snipboard.io/EKAz7j.jpg), the more you simplify it by deleting the pointy parts, the easier it gets to morph. Take note, in this example I also fixed your model to be manifold because yours [isn't manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry), in your case not airtight.